# Limit of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\sin(tx)dx$ as $|t|\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$, a Lebesgue integrable function in $\mathbb{R}$ ($\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f| < \infty$). Let:
$$
g(t) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\sin(tx)dx
$$
Show that $g$ is continuous (which I did), and that:
$$
\lim_{|t| \rightarrow \infty} g(t) = 0
$$

Why is the second part correct?

Thanks!

Comment: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8793/compute-integral-of-a-lebesgue-measurable-set) may help. AD.'s answer, in particular.

Comment: This is so called Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is trivial if $f$ is the characteristic function of an interval, and therefore also if it is a step function. Can you take it the rest of the way from there?

Comment: I can see why it is true for step-functions, and we can use the fact that the set of step-functions is dense in a closed interval, but how do we know whether or not there is a sequence of step-functions converging pointwise to f over the real line? Can we apply DCT?

Comment: @TheSubstitute I think using the DCT may be a bit tricky. But you can approximate any $L^1$ function with a simple function in the $L^1$ norm, and likewise any simple function with a step function (because any measurable set of finite measure can be approximated with a finite union of intervals). There are quite a number of details to fill in, and the step from approximating in the $L^1$ norm to proving the theorem for $L^1$ functions is a common stumbling block for beginning analysis students.