# Why is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\sin(tx)dx$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This is embarrassing.

I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113286/limit-of-int-infty-infty-fx-sintxdx-as-t-to-infty) question several months ago:

> Let $f$, a Lebesgue integrable function in $\mathbb{R}$
>   ($\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f| < \infty$). Let: $$g(t) :=
>  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\sin(tx)dx.$$ Show that $g$ is continuous
>   and that: $$ \lim_{|t| \rightarrow \infty} g(t) = 0. $$

I wrote there that I proved that $g$ is continuous, but I can't for life of me remember my proof, come up with a new one or find my notes. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show that for each $t$ and each sequence $\{t_n\}$ which converges to $t$ we have $g(t_n)\to g(t)$. To see this, define $F_n(x):=f(x)\sin(t_nx)$ and $F(x)=f(x)\sin(tx)$.

- By continuity of $y\mapsto \sin y$, we have $F_n(x)\to F(x)$ for each $x$.
- We have $|F_n(x)|\leq |f(x)|$ and $f$ is integrable.

Hence we can apply dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: It's actually the imaginary part of the Fourier transform of $f$.

Comment: The fact that the limit is zero is the Riemann-Lesbegue lemma.